# API Orders Search not accepting value

Tags: magento2, api

Doing an order search via API as follows:

```
{{magentoEndpoint}}/rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=pending&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

However, the following results come back:

```
{
    "items": [],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "status",
                        "value": "",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_count": 0
}
```

As you can see, the value parameter didn't come through.  Can anyone tell why?  Is there some trick to searching orders by status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the key was the order of the parameters.  When I changed it to field, then condition_type, then value in the querystring, it worked.